# Java: How to check for next ints without going to the next line (Scanner)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Quick Java question: So I have a set of integers on two different lines, however, I want to regard them in different scenarios.

So I have a for loop that I want to continue through a list of integers and add them to, say an ArrayList, but I want it to stop before going to the next line.

Like I would want it to stop at 2 in this situation:

```
1 4 2 91 4 0 2
3 5 8 6 9 88
```

hasNextInt() stops at 88 instead of 2 like I would want it to (which makes sense).

So my question: is there a way to make it stop before going to the next line? I tried both nextInt() and next() and they both continued to the next line.

My code:

```
while (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            if (stop == 'A')
                passengers.put(stop, scan.nextInt() + subtract);
            else 
                passengers.put(stop, passengers.get((char)(stop - 1)) + scan.nextInt() + subtract);
            System.out.println(passengers);
            if (scan.hasNext())
                subtract = scan.nextInt();
            else
                break;
            stop++;
        }
```

Comment: Consume a line at a time. Split the line on space, convert the resulting strings to ints.

Comment: do You want to read only single and first row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `hasNextLine()` in a `while` loop
2. read the *lines* using `nextLine()`
3. then split the values based on "space[s]"
4. Parse each value as an Integer
5. add them.

And *realize* OMG, this is faster than using `nextInt()`

Comment: @Maxitus - You are wc :)